# How to access headers in react.js frontend built by rails backend?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a get endpoint in billings_controller.rb like:

```
def index
  plans = PricingPlan.all  

  response.header['publishable-key'] = Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key]

  render json: { status: true, message: 'List of Plans.', data: plans.to_a }
end
```

Now, I would like to access that HTTP header in react.js front-end app, the way I'm doing is like:

```
componentDidMount() {
  zenApi.get(SERVER)
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({ pricing_plans: response.data, pub_key: response.headers['publishable-key'] });
  });
}
```

But the response.headers is undefined. console.log(response) gives as:

```
{status: true, message: "List of Plans.", data: Array(6)}
```

but, when I look HTTP response headers in network tab in chrome developers tools, it looks like:

```
 HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
 Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, PATCH
 Access-Control-Expose-Headers: access-token, expiry, token-type, uid, client
 Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
 publishable-key: pk_test_fYfWQWtbSsGbb1*****50VrT
 ETag: W/"15cb9de83c1d4eb95f83936d5413c695"
 Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
 X-Request-Id: b5288bbe-6783-4516-b628-110c1a29ea05
 X-Runtime: 0.593409
 Vary: Origin
```

I'm missing something or have't understood the concept I think. How can I access the "publishable-key: pk_test_fYfWQWtbSsGbb1*****50VrT" present in HTTP response header in react.js front-end.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You can access `$http` headers like this:`response.headers()`;

```
componentDidMount() {
  zenApi.get(SERVER)
  .then(response => {
   var headers = response.headers();
  var publishable_key =  headers['publishable-key']
    this.setState({ pricing_plans: response.data, pub_key: response.headers['publishable-key'] });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Ved, unfortunately your solution gives error as "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response.headers is not a function".